# Issues with encoding of a downloaded string (UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, FSharp.Data)

Tags: xml, utf-8, f#, f#-data

I am using the FSharp.Data for downloading and parsing an XML document. The document contains several nordic characters, like: "Lempäälän Keskus". I have a simple code like this:

```
open FSharp.Data
open System.IO

let xml = Http.RequestString(downloadUrl)
File.WriteAllText("response.xml", xml)
```

However, when I open the resulting file, the characters are corrupted and I see this: "LempÃ¤Ã¤lÃ¤n Keskus". I have tried manually re-saving the file with the ISO-8859-1 encoding and then reopening with UTF-8 (in VS Code). This fixed the displayed text. Then tried to implement a simple encoding conversion function:

```
open FSharp.Data
open System
open System.IO

let convertEncoding (input: string) =
  let iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
  let utf8 = Encoding.UTF8
  let isoBytes = iso.GetBytes(input)
  let utfBytes = Encoding.Convert(iso, utf8, isoBytes)
  utf8.GetString(utfBytes)

let xml = Http.RequestString(downloadUrl)
let decoded = convertEncoding xml
File.WriteAllText("response.xml", decoded)
```

However, when I open the file, I still see "LempÃ¤Ã¤lÃ¤n Keskus" instead of "Lempäälän Keskus". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this seems to be a weird behavior caused by the `Http` client from the `FSharp.Data` library. I am not sure whether this is a bug, or just a functionality that I haven't found the documentation for.

It is enough to replace the `FSharp.Data.Http` client with a `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`. Suddenly, all the encoding errors disappear and no conversion is needed whatsoever. Here is a sample solution:

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Net.Http

let download (url: string) = 
  async {
    use client = new HttpClient()
    let! xml = client.GetStringAsync(url) 
                |> Async.AwaitTask
    return xml
  }

let result = download url |> Async.RunSynchronously
File.WriteAllText("response.xml", result)
```

Answer (score 3):

Provide encoding when you write text to file

```
let encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
File.WriteAllText("response.xml", xml, encoding)
```

Comment: Thank you, but eventually I want to save the string into a database. Is it possible to convert it in such a way that it is in the correct format already in memory?

Comment: @Storm it depends on database you are going to use. But I would suggest you to use UTF-8

Comment: BTW your encoding conversion code is correct. Most likely you have a problem with the tool you use to open UTF-8 file. Make sure it's configured to UTF-8 and variable char width set (if there is such setting)

Answer (score 0):

[This is a bug](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data/issues/1251), for now the workaround is to use

```
Http.RequestString(..., responseEncodingOverride = "utf-8")
```